# Move records from Development to Production in CloudKit

Tags: production, records, cloudkit

I did something silly and made hundreds of records in Development environment in CloudKit. A previous thread mentioned that the records could be downloaded into a file and re-uploaded to the Production environment. Is there any other way I could do this, and if not, how would I go about downloading in records and storing it into a file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There is no option do do it in one run. You need one app that is connected to the development environment for reading your records. Then if you want to write to the production environment, you can only do that by re-signing your app. So indeed you first need to download all data, store them somewhere, and then writing them back to your production database.

Since the CKRecord complies to the NSCoding protocol you can write the results of your query directly to a file using:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(records, toFile: filePath)
```

Then if you want to read that file you can use:

```
result = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath)
```